# Rails - Setting user defined locals... Is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have tabs set up that will load a partial with stats from a specific time period, i.e.:

```
<%= render 'shared/user_reports' :locals => { :start_date => Date.today - 30, :end_date => Date.today } %>
```

The above would load the "Month" tab.

My question is, is there any way to get user defined dates passed to the `:start_date` and `:end_date` locals (without storing info in the database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to render your tab from an url like that `/my_path?start_date=2013-02-27&end_date=2013-03-27` :

```ruby
<%= render 'shared/user_reports' :locals => { 
     :start_date => (Date.parse(params[:start_date]) rescue Date.today - 1.month),
     :end_date => (Date.parse(params[:end_date]) rescue Date.today) 
} %>
```

But it's better to treat params in your controller :

```
@start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date]) rescue Date.today - 1.month
@end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date]) rescue Date.today
```

and in your view :

```
<%= render 'shared/user_reports' :locals => { :start_date => @start_date, :end_date => @end_date } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use URL parameters to store data temporarily.

Read the params using:

```
params[:param_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Date.parse to parse date from a string.

```
  1.9.3p327 :004 > start_date = Date.parse("march 27 2013")
  => Wed, 27 Mar 2013
```

So,

```
<%= render 'shared/user_reports' :locals => { :start_date => Date.parse("Feb 27 2013"), :end_date => Date.parse("March 27 2013") } %>
```

Will do.